# Event listener onMouseMove in react hooks: event object is undefined or clientX/Y are null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to bind a mouse move event to the thing. But what ever I do, either e is empty or e.clientX and Y is null.

```
const App = (props) => {
    const [move, setMove] = useState({"ix": 0, "iy": 0});

    const handleMove = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    }

    return (
        <div onMouseMove={handleMove} width="500" height="500"></div> //e exists but clientX is null
        <div onMouseMove={() => handleMove()} width="500" height="500"></div> //e undefined 
    );
}
```

console log:

```
{…}
_dispatchInstances: null
_dispatchListeners: null
_targetInst: null
altKey: 
bubbles: 
button: 
buttons:
cancelable: 
clientX: null
clientY: null
```

additionally I am flooded with this warning, which I don't understand even after reading the provided link

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `pageY` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist(). See https://fb me/react-event-pooling for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the synthetic event is pooled, all event properties are nullified after the event callback is invoked.

However, event properties can still be accessed like:

```
const handleMove = (e) => {
  console.log(e) // nullified object
  console.log(e.clientX); // has value
}
```

Or using `event.persist()` to remove this synthetic event from the pool.

```
const handleMove = (e) => {
  e.persist();
  console.log(e); // has value for clientX, etc
}
```

Comment: Ah ok that was it. So it doesn't pull the properties for performance reason but they get pulled when I directly access them, that's what the warning means.

Comment: right. since synthetic events are reused. i've added a workaround using `event.persist()` just for reference.

Comment: Just a note,  v17+ synthetic event don't use pool anymore so the second case won't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

What happens there, is that you're trying to `console.log()` a synthetic event. And `React` gives you that error. Which is completely reasonable, here's why,  as `React` documentation states:

> This synthetic event is **reused** for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property *pageY* on a *released/nullified* synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

So, a synthetic event object is reused by `React`. That's why, all the fields, will be nullified at the end of **every** event handler. It leads us to the the rule of thumb:

> You can't access synthetic event object is an **asynchronous** way.

This is why `React` was complaining, because you tried to access synthetic event object in your console, after synthetic event was nullified. The ways to get around that, is to either call `persist` function of synthetic event to persist all the fields  or just use the fields you need right away.

```
    const handleMove = (e) => {
        console.log(e); // <~ will cause error to come up
        console.log(e.pageY) // <~ no error
    }

    const handleMovePersist = (e) => {
        e.persist()
        console.log(e) // <~ no error, because synthetic event is persisted
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Does e.persist() have performance impact?

Comment: @Supertyp it has slight overhead since the persisted event is stored somewhere else (not anymore in the event pool).

Comment: Most likely, it won't, unless you use `persist` everywhere. Although, the question is 
why would you need to store the whole event? In pretty much all the cases you still end up using only a few, if not one field from an event.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the event.

```
<div onMouseMove={(e) => handleMove(e)} width="500" height="500"></div>
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

  

function App() {

  const [move, setMove] = useState({ ix: 0, iy: 0 });
  
  const getMousePos = e => {
    return { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY };
  };
  
  const handleMove = e => {
    console.log(getMousePos(e));
  };
  
  
  return (
    <div
        onMouseMove={e => handleMove(e)}
        style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", width: 500, height: 500 }}
      >
      </div>
  );
}
// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: This has the same result as onMouseMove={handleMove} (e is provided but clientX and Y are null)

Comment: @Supertyp please see the example above.

Comment: yes your code was not wrong but my problem was not that the event was not passed but that I can not access e as a whole, I need to access properties individually otherwise they are all nullified. btw I just tried, onMouseMove={handleMove} works as well apparently you can use both.

Comment: yes, depends how you pass the function, ```{func}``` and ```{(e) => func()e}``` both work.